# [ROS2] Service call keeps waiting for the service to be available

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ubuntu 20.04 + ROS2 foxy

I am trying to call a service from mavros package with ros2, but it gets stuck in `waiting for service to become available...`
I am pretty the service is available. I can see it with ros2 service list.
Is this a bug with ros2? foxy? I saw some issues on github about people complaining about bugs depending on the DDS, can this be related?

service call:

```
ros2 service call /mavros/cmd/arming mavros_msgs/srv/CommandBool '{value: True}'
waiting for service to become available...
```

ros2 service list:

```
ros2 service list -t | grep cmd
/mavros/cmd/arming [mavros_msgs/srv/CommandBool]
/mavros/cmd/command [mavros_msgs/srv/CommandLong]
```

Issue on github related to this: https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/issues/1718#issuecomment-1122646923

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400413/%5Bros2%5D-service-call-keeps-waiting-for-the-service-to-be-available/) by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2022-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated and restarted my computer and it worked...

---

Originally posted by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) with karma: 122 on 2022-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0